# Increase width without moving image

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, resize, width, pivot

I'm developing a drawing app, and I ran into a problem, and a possible solution would be to be able to resize horizontally (increase or decrease the width) of an image without altering it's pivot, but ending with a "directional resize", it means, that if I start dragging the right resize anchor, the image starts increasing it's width to the right, instead of always taking into consideration the pivot.

So, what I'm doing now is to increase the width and at the same time I move the image width/2, it works, however when I have to rotate the image.. everything starts to get broken, and even if I set the pivot in the middle of the sprite, since the image (that is contained inside the sprite) x is altered, it doesn't matter.

I've read some about matrices, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: This may be something you have tried, but have you experimented with altering the scaleX instead of the width? I'm not sure if that will cause the pivot to behave better

Answer (score 2):

There a few ways you can accomplish this.  The first is to use a transform matrix.
Here is a function I use to rotate an object around a point in that fashion:

*You'll need to import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer, if not using flashPro you can get it here:   https://code.google.com/p/artitem-as3/source/browse/trunk/ArtItem/src/fl/motion/MatrixTransformer.as?r=3

```
                 /**
                 * Rotates a displayObject around the passed local point.
                 * @param   displayObj
                 * @param   relativeDegrees - the relative amount of degrees to rotate the object
                 * @param   point - a local point to rotate the object around, if null, center of bounding box will be used.
                 */
                public static function rotateAroundPoint(displayObj:DisplayObject, relativeDegrees:Number, point:Point = null):void {
                    var m:Matrix  = displayObj.transform.matrix.clone();

                    if (!point) {
                        //default is center of bounding box
                        var r:Rectangle = displayObj.getBounds(displayObj);
                        point = new Point(r.x + (r.width * .5), r.y + (r.height * .5));
                    }
                    MatrixTransformer.rotateAroundInternalPoint(m, point.x, point.y, relativeDegrees);
                    displayObj.transform.matrix = m;
                }
```

Another more lazy way to do this, is to use a dummy parent object and just rotate that:

```
var dummy:Sprite = new Sprite();
dummy.addChild(yourObjectToRotate);

//this effectively makes the anchor point of dummy in the center, so when you rotate it it rotate from the center.
yourObjectToRotate.x = -(yourObjectToRotate.width * .5);
yourObjectToRotate.y = -(yourObjectToRotate.height * .5);

dummy.rotation = 90;
```